# How to get clickTAG url and click on that url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get clickTAG url and click on that url using jquery

here the sample code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="clickTAG=http://testing.com"></object>
```

Regards
Dev

Answer (score 1):

try this code, you will get `url` in variable now you can apply action on url eg. click or `window.location..`

```js
$(function() {
  $("object[flashvars^=clickTAG]").on('click', function(Event) {
    var url = $(this).attr('flashvars').split('=')[1];
    alert(url);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="clickTAG=http://testing.com">Object Test</object>
```

Comment: can i autoclick that url

Comment: yes you can add trigger `$("object[flashvars^=clickTAG]").trigger('click')` on document ready, but that is blocked due to browser security reason, may be you will need to allow once, the answer would be useful for `blocked popup` http://stackoverflow.com/a/23393900/926333

Comment: it's not working it's showing file:///C:/Users/ncpl/Desktop/ before url

Comment: at least run on server? not direct file

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = $("object").attr('flashvars');
var url = v.split('=')[1];
window.location.href = url;
```

This could get you to the url of the object!

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MR_Saberi/erpt80vt/)