# Close ad to continue as free user?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, visibility

I have a `300px x 250px` ad which is in this form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="advert.com" ></script>
```

I want to create a button underneath the ad which says:
"Close ad to continue as free user".

And once this button is clicked, the ad opens the `example.com` page on a new tab, and the ad disappears with the button

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Why are people negging this?

Comment: We cannot the question as-is, because we don't know what the script you used does exactly.

Comment: It just displays a 300 x 250 ad which opens the advert page when clicked..

Comment: It is impossible to answer since we have no clue how your ad script works. Plus most people here are not fans of forcing ad impression clicks.

Answer (score 1):

get the id or class of your ad with `var ad = document.querySelector("adId or adClass")`

get the id or class of your button that wil go underneath your add with `var button = document.querySelector("buttonId or buttonClass")`

then add a click event on the button with
`button.addEventListener("click", function(e){ ad.remove()})`

Answer (score -1):

Please use search in Stack Overflow before you ask a question. Look at this link:

[Javascript - Open Link in New Tab (SAME WINDOW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714366/javascript-open-link-in-new-tab-same-window)

Also you might like to read this:

[Javascript - Open a given URL in a new tab by clicking a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303964/javascript-open-a-given-url-in-a-new-tab-by-clicking-a-button)

But it is bad practice to use this because if you put to many adverts on the site user could never return to your site. Popups make users angry.

EDIT:

We need to know more about your script. You could set the display css property on the div element to none; or visibility to hidden. to do this in pure javascript you should use something like that:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style
```

[Here's a good description.](http://w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)

Comment: to close add you should tell us more about your script. It could be set css property on the div element like 
display: none; 
or 
visibility: hidden;
to do this in pure javascript you should use something like that:

document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style

The best description you have there:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp